# Filter data on django admin console with URL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

Is there any way to filter modal data on Django admin console with URL and POST request?

I have a dynamic URL which I am creating on the basis of filters on template. 
As this is a GET request and length of URL depends on the results filtered. 
HTTP URL has length restriction. For smaller number of results it is working fine but problem with very long number of results.
Is there any other way to filter data on admin console or is there any way to filter results rendered with POST request?
Otherwise there is overhead to create custom template which may lead to performance and other issues for large numbers of records (>4K).

```
url = self.reverse("admin:appName_modalName_changelist") + "?id__in=" + ",".join(
                [str(x) for x in records.values_list("id", flat=True)])
```